How to resolve path aliases in TypeScript during build process?
Question:
I'm working on a TypeScript project and using path aliases for cleaner import statements. However, I am facing issues when building my project where the TypeScript compiler fails to resolve these path aliases. I have set up my tsconfig.json with path aliases, but the build process does not recognize them.
Configuration details:

tsconfig.json setup:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}


I use the following build script in package.json:
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc"
}



Example TypeScript Code:
Let's assume you have the following directory structure:
project
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── utils
│       └── helper.ts
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json

src/utils/helper.ts:
export const greet = (name: string) => {
  return `Hello, ${name}!`;
};

src/index.ts:
import { greet } from '@/utils/helper';

console.log(greet('World'));

Error:
When you run the build script npm run build, you might encounter an error if the path aliases are not resolved correctly:
Error: Cannot find module '@/utils/helper'

Expected Output:
I expect the TypeScript compiler to correctly resolve path aliases during the build process, resulting in a successful compilation of my code.
Additional Information:
I have tried using npx tsconfig-paths, but I encounter issues where it cannot determine the executable to run.
Could someone provide guidance on resolving this issue with path alias resolution during the build process in TypeScript?

This is explicitly out of scope for TypeScript itself: "Note that this feature does not change how import paths are emitted by tsc, so paths should only be used to inform TypeScript that another tool has this mapping and will use it at runtime or when bundling."
